# Sci-fi novel about a woman who is cryogenized throughout millennia

Tags: story-identification, novel, cryogenics

I do not remember as to why she is cryogenized in the first place, but the device is pretty resilient and supports her waking in different periods of Earth evolution, when, by various events, she is forced to reenter the device to escape danger, and sleep until the next period. I think the last awakening is some million years in the future, when she witnesses a cataclysmic event (the Sun dying perhaps?). 
For a while I thought is one of Asimov's novels, but after searching high and low, I'm not so sure anymore.

It wasn't specifically freezing, more like suspended animation by some substances with tubes connecting to the veins.

I'm not so sure when I read it, perhaps like 15-20 years ago. But it wasn't a new novel even then.

Comment: Any idea when you read it? When do you think it was written?

Comment: Here's a little [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help you with some possible questions to help you add more details

Comment: Also, it might help to know specifically, is it actually suspended animation by FREEZING or are you just using that term as a catchall and it might be say a magic "stasis field" or something to that effect?  Sometimes lists of these types of stories are separated specifically by the method and it might help to know how certain you are.

Comment: I'm not so sure, perhaps like 15-20 years ago, but it wasn't a new novel even then. @starpilotsix it wasn't specifically freezing, more like suspended animation by some substances with tubes connecting to the veins

Comment: @Razvan I've added that information into your question. Please [edit] any additional details into your question if you remember anything else.